# HOW TO: FIX ERROR - "the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel, oledb

While uploading excel this issue is raising.
I set Application pool 32 bit false and it works fine.
After two weeks it again raising the same issue.

Comment: Do you mean the "Application Pool 32 bit" flag is reset to true again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this **2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components**

Path:

[Use this link to download 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

If this is not what you expected then below link may help you

[Solutions for Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 issues](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)